# Change button navigation text "Next" / "Previous"

Tags: docusaurus

in docusaurus 2 the docs navigation buttons has a text "Next" or "Previous". I wonder if there is way to modify or personalize these texts. My documentation site is in Spanish and its quite awkward having distinct languages in the same page.
Thanks.

This image shows what I refer to:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to swizzle the `DocPaginator` component to do that - https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes/#swizzling-theme-components

Comment: How do you swizzle the DogPaginator component? For me trying to do it gives the following error: 

Component "DocPaginator" doesn't exists. "DocPaginator" is swizzled instead of "DocPaginator".

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to change some css with the class

```
.pagination-nav
```

I got rid off "next" and "previous" by setting this class to display:none

```
.pagination-nav__sublabel
```

But haven't tried to get text into it.